# Jackson: vary JSON property value by view

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson, I know that I can include / exclude a property from serialization for a view by using `@JsonView`.

How can I vary a JSON property's value by view?

e.g., I might want a property's value in view A to be the whole object, in view B to be the object with certain properties filtered out, in view C, I just want it to be the "id" (no object), and in view D, I might want it to be the "name" (no object):

```
// view A JSON
{
    "prop": {"id": 123, "name": "abc", "description": "def"}
}

// view B JSON
{
    "prop": {"id": 123, "name": "abc"}
}

// view C JSON
{
    "prop": 123
}

// view D JSON
{
    "prop": "abc"
}
```

Comment: +1, it is a good question. In your example I normally generate `{"prop":{"id":123}}` to view `C` and `{"prop":{"name":"abc"}}` to view `D`. I also want to know how to remove the property name when there is only one with value ;)

Comment: You can achieve A and B using standard `@JsonView`, but not C and D.  Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/440

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this using generics but you also need to know in advance what concrete class to use, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final MyStuff<Prop> myStuff = mapper.readValue("{\"prop\": {\"id\": 123, \"name\": \"abc\", \"description\": \"def\"}}", MyStuff.class);
    final MyStuff<String> myStuff1 = mapper.readValue("{\"prop\": \"abc\"}", MyStuff.class);
    final MyStuff<Integer> myStuff2 = mapper.readValue("{\"prop\": 123}", MyStuff.class);
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Prop {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class MyStuff<T> {

    private T prop;

    public T getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(T prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

so not sure if this is what you want.